# UWP Print PopupUI Close button handle

Tags: c#, uwp

Am developing UWP app with Printing Option. I need to handle if customer click on "Close" button on PrintUI popup.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I got finally. I found in Print Task Completed event .Check from here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.printing.printtaskcompletion